# Issue with installing rails plugin (restful_authentication)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, restful-authentication

I am trying to install restful_authentication plugin in my machine which is running rails -v 2.3.5. I get the following error when i try to install it

```
ruby script/plugin install http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication.git restful_authentication
Plugin not found: ["http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication.git", "restful_authentication"]

ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication.git restful_authentication
Plugin not found: ["git://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication.git", "restful_authentication"]
```

how am i supposed to install the plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just download the plugin [here](https://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication) and put it inside vendor/plugins manually.

Direct link for the download: https://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication/tarball/master

So the directory structure should be: vendor/plugins/restful_authentication

Comment: I never knew I can install a plugin that way. Thanx